# Is there support for internal locations on Google Calendar?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

Is there support for internal office locations on Google Calendar?

We have a bunch of meeting rooms and that's what appears in the Location field of an event. However, Google can't resolve that to a location?

Is it possible to establish some sort of URL that is opened when users click on our meeting room links, rather than Google passing it off to Google Maps?

Comment: Are you using Google Apps, or just the regular consumer Google Calendar?

Comment: Google Apps - tags updated

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the `map` link next to the **Where** field in the calendar, I would +1 this (if only stack exchange were a feature request forum)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are already using the calendar Resources feature. If not, you can set those up in the admin panel.

When you create resources, you can add a URL to each resource. Then when a user adds the resource to a meeting, that URL goes into the "Where:" field. We use this for GoToMeeting accounts and it works great (you set up a recurring meeting and use that as the URL). For physical locations, it would be as pretty but it should work. Definitely a bit of a hack but it gets the job done for my company (only 25 employees).

Here is a good guide on creating resources - http://www.googlegooru.com/how-to-create-a-resource-in-google-calendar/

Comment: I realize this is an old answer and may be outdated, but from what I can tell by watching Youtube tutorials, there's no option to add a URL and override the map link: http://i.imgur.com/0zhDL6v.png

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the comment by @Sleavely it doesn't appear there's native support for a URL tied to a resource unless perhaps through its user description. I'm not an admin to carry out the experimentation however.

I've uncovered a bit about what is supported which I'll walk through here.

The `Resources.calendars` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars) under the `G Suite Admin SDK > Directory API` lists the following json schema for the supported resource attributes:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#resources#calendars#CalendarResource",
  "etags": etag,
  "resourceId": string,
  "resourceName": string,
  "generatedResourceName": string,
  "resourceType": string,
  "resourceDescription": string,
  "resourceEmail": string,
  "capacity": integer,
  "buildingId": string,
  "floorName": string,
  "floorSection": string,
  "resourceCategory": string,
  "userVisibleDescription": string,
  "featureInstances": [
    {
      "feature": resources.features Resource
    }
  ],
  "featureInstances": string
}
```

I'm wondering if perhaps the `userVisibleDescription` is one avenue to tuck in an internal URL dedicated to a conference room, as in some [visual directory](https://www.officespacesoftware.com/features/visual-directory) url for instance, or a confluence page, etc.

Drilling a bit further around over in the Help Center we find the following documentation: [Set up buildings, features, and other resources](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1033925?hl=en#). Under section *Step 3: Add resources* there's the *upload resources via CSV in bulk* section which links to the [Format for bulk updates](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1033925?hl=en#calendar-format) documentation. The entries under the section *Format for resources and features* lists the following properties:

> **Required Properties**
>
> > - Resource Id
> > - Resource Name
> > - Building Id
> > - Resource Category
> > - Floor
> > - Name
> > - Capacity
>
> **Optional Properties**
>
> > - Resource Type
> > - Floor Section
> > - User Visible Description
> > - Description
> > - #Feature
> > - Autogenerated name

The candidate worth experimenting on is the User Visible Description which is a

> ### User Visible Description
>
> Free-form description of the room that is visible to users in the room details.

To get visual with things, I'm wondering where exactly the user description renders for the conference room resource field in a calendar event.
[image: dummy meeting pointing out the conference room field]

Worth posting the current fields when creating a calendar event, which clearly differentiates rooms from locations. One complicating matter is that Zoom claims the location URL for itself. Which appears to be technique for adding an arbitrary URL. If that's the case calendar events would only be able to support one URL, still unclear whether or not user descriptions can embed anchor urls, etc.
[image: new calendar event]